# Rephrasing this phrase "through this three-year journey" so that it can be read aloud less awkwardly?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

I am not a native English speaker and I wrote the phrase "Through this three-year journey". Then I found it awkward to be read aloud because there are three consecutive words in the phrase that begin with "th".

I wonder if there is a phrase such that it is equivalent in meaning to the given phrase and one can read it aloud more fluently and easily?

Comment: I think you should practice your enunciation rather than looking for potentially unnatural phrasing to avoid usages that you might currently find tricky to say out loud. You might also consider copying Cockneys - replace the first consonant in *through* and *three* (not *this*) with **F**. Nobody is likely to criticise you, and you'll at least be easily understood.

Comment: Oh thank you. You meant my phrase is okay for a native speaker to read aloud?

Comment: I'm not a linguist, but to me the difference between the initial consonant in, say, ***this*** and ***thin*** is quite extreme. You can get away with ***fin*** for the second if that's any easier, so you just need to work on the other sound to start with.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know what alternative or alternatives of "this" you may suggest? :)

Comment: Would "through such a three-year journey" make easy?

Comment: I can only repeat what I said. Don't distort your use of language just because you find certain English phonemes difficult. The original ***this*** means ***exactly** the actual one being spoken of*, but ***such a*** means ***any** journey **like** the one being spoken of*. Focus on using the right word for what you mean - just enunciate it as best you can. Your speech will probably improve with practice, but if you start learning inappropriate *vocabulary* shifts you're likely to end up with bad habits which will be difficult to overcome.

Comment: I think it will be a little hard for us to rephrase it without context (although I agree with everyone else that it would probably be good for you to practice and read it without making changes). I would probably look for a synonym for "though," and possibly add an adjective like "long" or "amazing" between "this" and "three", if you want to break it up a little. "During this long, three-year journey..."

Comment: Note that there are **two different sounds** which are spelled ‹th›. One is 'voiced' (there is a 'hum' while you say it - IPA /ð/) -- this is the sound in *this*. The other is 'unvoiced' (there is no hum - IPA /θ/) -- this is the sound in *through* and *three*. So you don't have the same sound three times in a row.

Comment: Following up on StoneyB's comment about voiced/voiceless: one must *fully* say say each word including any expulsion of breath at the end and including any positioning of lips and jaw required to produce that sound, before one moves on to the next word; otherwise there is the chance that the initial consonant of the next word could be distorted by the not-yet-complete sound that preceded it. Sometimes the ending sound of a word merges easily and readily with the beginning sound of the next word; but sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a native AmE speaker and this does not sound awkward to me when I read it aloud.

The *th* in *this* is voiced, so it's actually a different sound than the *th* in *through* or *three*.

Nonetheless, both are not uncommon sounds in the beginning of English words.

> These three things belong to me.
>
> Take this through the machine over there.
>
> I feel that the thrill is gone.

If you still want an equivalent phrase easier for you to say, try something like *During our three-year journey* or *During my three-year journey*.  *Three* is a basic word in English, being a number, and there's no easy way to substitute that, though.

Answer (score 2):

If (as has been my experience with other non-native, particularly Chinese-background, speakers) you mean journey figuratively (as opposed to literally), then equivalent phrase alternatives could include:

> over the last three years

or

> during that three year period

(Depending on whether the "Journey" has continued to the present day or terminated in the past)

On the other hand, if a literal journey is in view, "along" could be substituted for "through" in the original phrase.

Comment: Thanks so much. I would like to use "journey" in a figurative sense.